# Генерация изображений с random patterns

Tags: css, css3, svg, inkscape

Я пытался создать специальный `random pattern`.
 Например, случайные черные точки, как на рисунке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, мне необходимо гораздо большее изображение, чем на рисунке, с 100 000 точек / кругов.
В принципе, никаких проблем, но SVG с несколькими `МБ` становится слишком большим, чтобы открыть его, например, с помощью Inkscape, потому что каждый круг нарисован индивидуально.
Принимаю любые идеи, как это может быть реализовано лучше, чтобы получить в результате  меньший файл. Я уже пробовал с `pattern`.
 Проблема в том, что это должен быть по-настоящему случайный, неповторяюшийся шаблон.

Не нужно это делать с точками, которые могут также выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Источник:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44242344/7394871)

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44242344/7394871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно его сочетать из меньших повторяющихся кусков, я имею ввиду не просто одинаковые квадраты, а большие области которые пересекаясь накладываются друг на друга, а значит общее число точек для сохранения уменьшается. Но не уверен что это спасёт Inscape, так как он может виснуть и значительно на меньших изображениях.

Поясню, всего может быть например 100 случайных линий (фрагментов), но за счёт их случайного расположения на холсте и повторения картинка будет полностью рандомной и не иметь повторяющегося паттерна.

Я делал концентрические круги на Inscape и их было порядка 30, и при этом программа дико тормозила... возможно просто нужно другой редактор использовать и это решит проблему.

**UPD:**

Можно варьировать количество патернов (одинаковых), их размер, количество каждого в общей картинке. Так же изменение масштаба при наложении каждого отдельного паттерна на общую картинку. В примере используется два паттерна, и различными вращениями и положением из них собирается общая картинка. Для вашей задачи разных паттернов может быть например 100, а использование каждого например 10-20.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приведённом примере используется 2 паттерна и около 5 использований каждого.

Comment: добавил в текст в середину пояснение

Comment: Благодарю.  Ещё будет лучше, если вы добавите свою работу, можно картинку

Comment: Я могу пример сделать обычной картинкой?

Comment: @Alexandr_T могу обычной картинкой сделать, без кода SVG, для демонстрации самой идеи.

Comment: @Alexandr_T сделал картинкой и написал описание поподробнее.

Comment: @Alexandr_T :)))

Answer (score 3):

Это что-то вроде того, что вам надо?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="600">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dots" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feTurbulence baseFrequency=".1" numOctaves="1" seed="42" />
      <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
      <feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="2" />
       <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600" style="fill:#888; stroke:#bbd; stroke-width:2px; filter: url(#dots)" />
</svg>
```

**Как это работает:**

1. `<feTurbulence baseFrequency=".1" numOctaves="1" seed="42" />`

Генерирует некоторый случайный шум. Удалите атрибут `seed`, если вы хотите, чтобы каждый раз был выбран другой pattern.

2. `<feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>` преобразует шум в `greyscale`

3.`<feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="2" />`
размывает шаблон `noisey`, так что точки немного сливаются. Поэкспериментируйте с этим значением, чтобы изменить `blobbiness`.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246620/7394871)